# Can't delete an invited user from Azure Active Directory

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I'm trying  Azure Active Directory for the first time, I invited a user with his email but after that I accepted the invitation since I own the email I could not delete the user from: Users | All users (Preview).
What is the cause of the problem?

Comment: Why can't you delete? Are you getting a message? Is the UI disabled? Something else?

Comment: Make sure your account is at least a **User Administrator** (Global admin is also OK as BowmanZhu mentioned) in Azure AD. See [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/active-directory-users-assign-role-azure-portal#assign-roles) to learn how to assign AAD role to your account.

Answer (score 0):

1, First, make sure you have permission to do the delete operation(I'm the global admin of the subscription, and it works fine on my side).

**Update: As Allen mentioned, please make sure your account is User admin.**

2, And after you delete the user, you need to refresh the browser.

If you get some errors on this problem, please share.:)